# How to Signing the Android Application Package (Visual Studio with Xamarin)?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, package, keystore

**How to Signing the Android Application Package (Visual Studio with Xamarin) ?**

Answer (score 0):

Pre Xamarin 4.2
In visual studio

1. Switch to Release mode and Build (f6)
2. Select Android product in the solution explorer.
3. Hit tooks -> android -> publish
4. Follow the instructions to sign and align

4.2 Changed things.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/

Comment: im getting this message <img src="https://fonebay.com/unchecked.png" width="600" height="276">

Comment: I looked at the image and it appears you are using Xamarin studio, not Visual Studio.  I'm not sure exactly where it is in Xamarin studio, but in VS here is what you do. 1. Open the project menu and select the last item "app name" properties. 2. Go to the Android options tab. 3. Make sure the Configuration drop down is set to Release. 4. Uncheck the "Use Shared Runtime" checkbox. 5. Save and try again.